# Windows 10: dedicated graphic card driver stopped working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

since some days the Nvidia GTX 760M of my Asus N56JR it's starting to reporting a problem and I can't use it anymore for games. I can't open the control panel and if I go in device manager I found that windows reports an error on it:

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems.
>   (Code 43)

I searched google for a solution but none of them worked.
I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling the nvidia drivers (and software), tried do use a tool called DDU (display driver uninstaller) and also used a registry cleaner as suggested but I had no luck.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

after uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers about 10 times it finally worked...

EDIT: after nearly a month, the problem presented again, solved (momentary I think) thanks to militarylions here:https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/861231/geforce-drivers/nvidia-amp-windows-10-how-i-solved-the-code-43-error-/post/4762989/#4762989

> TRY THIS SOLUTION FIRST IT'S THE EASIEST
>
> SOLUTION: (for me)
>   -It's static build up in your computer
>   -I have an Asus w/ 745m Q550L that you can't take the battery off
>   -I unplugged the computer after turning it off
>   -Held down the power button for over a minute (it'll flash on for 2 seconds then turns right off)
>   -It discharges the build up
>   -Plugged it back in, reboot, and works perfectly fine, no more Error Code 43
>
> hope this helps